# Move the file with particular extension

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm new to vb scripting and I'm trying to move the file which has only certain extension say for example txt or jpg.

I have a script here like this:

```
filePath = directoryLocation + fileName + "*.txt|jpg"
fso.MoveFiles source,destination
```

when I run this, its throwing an error saying `Bad file name or number.`.

Why the wildcard character `|` doesn't work here?

Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Nope didnt work. Guess its not with regex, but something to do with vb script itself.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `MoveFile` (and similar, eg `CopyFile`) method only supports the `*` and `?` wildcards. Looking at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6(v=vs.84).aspx) documentation, only `*` and `?` are mentioned - although I could not immediately find anything that explicitly states what wildcards are supported.

Thus in your scenario you will simply need to apply both patterns:

```vb
filePath = fso.BuildPath(directoryLocation, fileName & "*.txt")
fso.MoveFile filePath, destination

filePath = fso.BuildPath(directoryLocation, fileName & "*.jpg")
fso.MoveFile filePath, destination
```

Note that you will need to handle the error which occurs when no file names are matched:

> An error also occurs if a wildcard character that is used in source doesn't match any files. The MoveFile method stops on the first error it encounters. No attempt is made to roll back any changes made before the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards don't work for building paths or regular file operations, you cannot use * or |

Try this instead:

```
For Each file In fso.GetFolder(directoryLocation).Files
    If LCase(file.Name) = LCase(filename & ".txt") Or LCase(file.Name) = LCase(filename & ".jpg") Then
        fso.MoveFile file.Path, 'destination
    End If
Next
```

Comment: No * is working for me. Only `|` is not working for me.